# Locking row for two updates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I need to do two updates to rows but I need to make sure they are done together and that no other query from another user could interfere with them. I know about `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` but I imagine after the first update it will of course be unlocked which means someone could interfere with the second update. If someone else updates that row first, the update will work but will mess up the data. Is there anyway to ensure that the two updates happen how they are supposed to? I have been told about transactions but as far as I know they are only good for making sure the two updates actually happen and not whether they happen "together," unless I am mistaken and the rows will be locked until the transaction is committed?

Here are the queries:

`SELECT z FROM table WHERE id='$id'`

`UPDATE table SET x=x+2 WHERE x>z`

`UPDATE table SET y=y+2 WHERE y>z`

I made a mistake and didn't give full information. That was my fault. I have updated the queries. The issue I have is that z can be updated as well. If z is updated after the SELECT but before the other two updates, the data can get messed up. Does doing the transaction BEGIN/COMMIT work for that?

Comment: See mysql TRANSACTIONS (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html), and work together with PHP (or any language) and MYSQL.

Comment: @GabrielSantos I mentioned transactions. Will anything locked in the middle of the transaction stay locked until the commit?

Comment: Qitch if some data are not updated, you do a rollback and send a warning for user. See http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-mysql/php-mysql-and-transaction-begin-commit-rollback/

Comment: @GabrielSantos As I mentioned in my post, the data would still be able to update, it could just end up updating incorrectly.

Comment: Do you need to just get a piece of data for an update? If so, just use a subquery. Otherwise, you could consider using the `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT;` statement. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html)

Comment: Transactions will make sure any read queries see either the previous state, or updated new state (both rows).  Make sure you're using InnoDB and read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Don't understand. If first user update, and second update together a record, you need to store two updates in one line of table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about TRANSACTION
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

```
[... connect ...]

mysql_query("BEGIN");

$query1 = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET x=x+2 WHERE x>y');
$query2 = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET y=y+2 WHERE y>y');

if($query1 && $query2) {
    mysql_query("COMMIT");  
    echo 'Save Done. All UPDATES done.';  
} else {
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");  
    echo 'Error Save. All UPDATES reverted, and not done.';  
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake and didn't give full information. That was my fault. I have updated the queries. The issue I have is that `z` can be updated as well. If `z` is updated after the SELECT but before the other two updates, the data can get messed up. Does doing the transaction `BEGIN/COMMIT` work for that?

Comment: Put all inside one only transaction, if any condition fail all your data will be reverted with one `ROLLBACK`. `if($query1 && $query2 && $query3) { COMMIT } else { ROLLBACK }`

Comment: The queries won't necessarily fail though, they could just end up inserting bad data, if I am thinking about it correctly? This means it wouldn't roll back because as far as it's concerned it succeeded. This could just be me not understanding exactly how transactions work which is why I'm confused.

Comment: All `UPDATES`, `INSERTS` or etc are not stored until you do the last query: `mysql_query("COMMIT");`

Comment: You can drop a table or delete a database, but, if you do the ROLLBACK, the table/database is secure.

Comment: So if I lock my `SELECT` that should be sufficient in making sure nothing funky is selected as other users would have to wait until the commit to be able to start that first query, right?

Comment: No no no. TRANSACTION are the secure way to save, update, insert, etc any data assuming a list of conditions, but, you can't lock the table avoiding another user to update some row, with mysql.

Comment: Ok, so I get the transaction is enough. However, I was talking about row locking which you can do in innodb.

Comment: I can't help with innodb row lock because I have no mastery of the subject. But, you can ask here: dba.stackexchange.com and see this in special: dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/innodb-row-locking-how-to-implement

Answer (score 0):

There are various levels of transaction, but basically as per [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties you should expect that within a given transaction, all reads and updates are performed **consistently** meaning it will be kept in a valid state, but more importantly a transaction is **isolated** in that work being done in another transaction (thread) will not interfere with your transaction (your grouping of select & update SQL statements):  this allows you to take a broad assumption that you are the only thread of execution within the system allowing you to commit that group of work (**atomically**) or roll it *all* back.

Each database may handle the semantics differently (some may lock rows or columns, some may re-order, some may serialize) but that's the beauty of a declarative database interface:  you worry about the work you want to get done.

As stated, on MySQL InnoDB is transactional and will support what is mentioned above so ensure your tables are organized with InnoDB, other non-transactional engines (e.g. MyISAM) are not transactional and thus will force you to manage those transactional semantics (locking) manually.

Comment: Going by transactions and my queries up above, if a user ends upperforming a transaction where `z` gets updated, is there any possibility that someone in another transaction could select the old value of `z` due to timing and then perform the other queries under the guise of the old `z` value when in fact `z` had already been updated by another user?

Comment: Complicated, it is possible that another transaction #2 could see the old value of z whilst transaction #1 is in process under lower *isolation levels*.  In this case, you'll want to verify serializable isolation.  Good read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to lock the entire table:

```
LOCK TABLE `table` WRITE;
SELECT z FROM `table` WHERE id='$id';
UPDATE `table` SET x=x+2 WHERE x>z;
UPDATE `table` SET y=y+2 WHERE y>z;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This will prevent other sessions from writing, and reading, from the `table` table during the SELECTs and UPDATEs.

Whether this is an appropriate solution does depend on how appropriate it is for sessions to wait to read or write from the table.

Comment: If user close the browser before save a locked form, the table will remain locked.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Do you have a reference to explain that? I suspect either the PHP script will continue running, and unlock the table, or the script will abort, disconnect from the database, and the lock will be released.

Comment: Michal, your sample are secure, but, if I go edit news id 5, for instance, I say: MYSQL, lock news with id 5 and unlock only when I save. If I don't save, the row continue locked (like a Joomla website, where I need to unlock locked rows every time I close the page without save).

Comment: Gabriel, firstly to clarify, I wasn't locking any specific rows in my answer, but the entire table. Secondly, from what I can tell, ["locking" in Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/What_do_the_locks_mean_and_how_do_you_get_rid_of_them%3F) is implemented by some other application-specific means than native MySql locking , and last longer than a single http request. Thridly, according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html 'If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the session'

Comment: To clarify further: 1) The 5 lines of code I wrote will run in one http request, and so the browser closing afterwards should have no affect. 2) The connection from PHP to MySql just lasts for one http request. No matter what, once that request has finished, PHP will be disconnected from MySQL, and therefore releasing all MySQL table locks. (Although of course other PHP connections to MySQL could be happening independently)